# Scroll to the bottom in Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a list template that looks like:

```
{{#each item}}
  {{ this }}
{{/each}}
```

The item in that helper is a database cursor that looks like this:

```
Items.find({ group: Session('group') });
```

So as the group changes the template re-renders. I want the template to be scrolled to the bottom every time the template re-renders as in the item listing changes. I use `el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;` to scroll to the bottom and this code is placed inside the rendered callback. But when the template *re-renders* the callback isn't fired. Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking into Template.autorun which can be used inside created or rendered. The key is the assignment to a reactive collection, in this case the Session object.

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){
    this.autorun(function(){
        var group = Session.get("group");
        // rest of code here
    });
});
```

Meteor docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun